# HTML Select Box with multiple links and button

Tags: html

I have a select box and a button:

```
  <form target="_blank" action="document.getElementById('pages').value">

    <select class="aa" name="pages" id="pages">
      <option value="www.google.com" style="color:#d15347">Google</option>
      <option value="www.facebook.com" style="color:#d15347">Facebook</option>
      <option value="www.twitter.com" style="color:#d15347">Twitter</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" class="button2"><span> GO </span></button>
  </form>
```

Whenever I select one website and click on button GO, i want to go to the companie's page. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

**Note** the _blank will not work at SO due to sandbox - it generates a

> Blocked opening 'https://www.google.com/' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

but should work at your site

NOTE also you need to remove the `name` attribute to not pass the value of the select onto the site you open

Full page example

http://plungjan.name/SO/selectasite/index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form links</title>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        this.action = document.getElementById("pages").value;
      })
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" target="_blank">
    <select class="aa" id="pages">
      <option value="https://www.google.com" style="color:#d15347">Google</option>
      <option value="https://www.facebook.com" style="color:#d15347">Facebook</option>
      <option value="https://www.twitter.com" style="color:#d15347">Twitter</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" id="go" class="button2"><span> GO </span></button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I do it without the window.addeventListener? 
Or can your formalize an HTML page with all the <> needed for the form and on submit

Comment: Bro, the weblink isnt opening in a new blank page. He concats the urls and stays in the same, something like: https://localhost......www.google.pt

Comment: That is because you need to add protocol like I did https://

Comment: Also you did not ask for a new blank page: _I want to go to the company’s page_ - Ther target="blank" should open in a new tab in the first example. Also pls do not call me “bro”

Comment: those urls arent working. i went to https://twitter.com/?pages=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.twitter.com instead of https://twitter.com

Comment: Im using ur last example of code. used the _blank in form and idk why this is happening. i want to go to a clear page, doesnt need to be a new tab, but to that specific url (the value)

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean. We need to remove the name from the select inthe form

Comment: See update and updated page http://plungjan.name/SO/selectasite/

Comment: it doesnt work... the url sends me to my current directory/local host